# Запросы по семантическому ядру

Tags: seo, оптимизация-сайтов, семантика, продвижение

Ребят собираю ядро для продвижения задаюсь вопросом как правильно поступить, подскажите пожалуйста.
Кей коллектор собрал мне запросы (дизайн сайта, дизайн сайтов, дизайн сайту, дизайн сайты) как правильно выделить их в кластер? 
Нужно все оставлять или выбрать 1, а остальные поисковик сам будет методом склонения подтягивать? 
Как лучше размещать выбранный запрос в текст точным вхождением или разбавляя дополнительным словом?

Answer (score 0):

1) Для поисковика все эти запросы синонимы, в текст нужно вставить один из них, иначе высока вероятность применения фильтра "переоптимизация" за заспамленость!

2) По поводу кластера - лучше использовать программу 'Key Assort' - она автоматически разбивает слова на кластеры.

3) В вашем случае, для анализа эффективности ключей нужно снять частотность"!" (это частотность строгая, включая склонения) и если по ключевикам: (дизайн сайта, дизайн сайтов, дизайн сайту, дизайн сайты) есть высокая частотность"!" (выше 20 в мес) то лучше их оставить!)))
PS.: Если помог, плз примите ответ (галочка над ответом).

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что в вопросе слиты в едино разные задачи:

1. Найти запросы и составить семантическое ядро (список слов для
   оптимизации).  **Это у вас готово**
2. Распределить эти поисковые запросы по страницам сайта.
3. Для выбранных страниц сделать техническое задание на тексты.

Отсюда следующее:

- Для семантического ядра лучше собирать точные вхождения.
- Для выбранных страниц составить задание на тексты, где присутствуют прямые и непрямые вхождения.